# My question was put on hold as I changed its title, should I change it back to the previous title?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I changed the title of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272638/what-is-a-program-rather-than-implementation-of-an-algorithm) of mine which have more than 8 answers and one accepted answer to match it with the question; but it was immediately put on hold. Should I change it back to its previous title?

About the question itself, I referenced my answer to some scientific pages which correspond to my question. I edited it many times to clarify it and now don't see much unclear things in it, please note I can't change the question totally regarding the existing answers (then they might become irrelevant, could I do that?), I kept those things which was referenced on the answers intact, but yet my question is clear. If it is not, please tell me.

Or maybe I should have asked it in another website? for example CS.stackexchange.com? I personally think my three or two recent questions fit more in the CS.stackexchange.com. and it's possible that users here don't expect more academical questions here.

Comment: I started editing your question to make it more clear based on the answers. All I could come up with is a single sentence. "Is a program also an algorithm?" Do you think this is an accurate representation of your question?

Comment: Thank you I used your suggestion and tried to shorten my questions.

Comment: @Snowman This question was mostly resulted from a confusion about the term of program and algorithm. Please consider my last update. I yet think the question is helpful for other people who may have a similar confusion.

Comment: At this point I would just move on. Yes, it was closed. Yes, you got the answer you wanted. Yes, you learned how to ask better questions. That is a win all around.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that question is not the title. As I read it I have a very difficult time figuring out what your actual problem is that you are trying to solve. You also seem to have multiple questions mixed together. I also believe that question is *probably* not off-topic here, but it is difficult to say without clarification.

A good question is just as long as it needs to be. It has a clear, concise problem statement and the necessary supporting information (but not too much).

To answer your question about my edit, I do not remember what I did (I cannot see the edit history) but it may have been spelling or grammar. When I edit a title, it is normally to make it clear, concise, and accurate. Titles are what show up in the question list, and a reader should be able to understand what the question is about at a glance.

Comment: I didn't say you edited it? did I? anyway I revised it yet another time, the problem statement now is more clear and relevant to the current answers specially my final answer. Do you think its still unclear?